# Make awk keep the input formating spacing intact for output

Tags: awk

I want to print the input column ASCII data file with only some specific columns modified.
If I use awk to modify the columns (e.g.: $NF=99), when I finally give the "print $0" command, it prints the output correctly, but all the space padding, formatting etc of other columns are gone. (They all basically gets replaced by the OFS).

Is there any way to make awk print exactly the same input with changes ONLY in the specified columns?
I need to give this output to another fortran code, which has very strict read formats. So I cannot afford to change the formatting of line.

If awk is not the software I should use for this purpose, what would you suggest?

---

Update: Example:

Input entry in a row.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1936 24170  2536  1987 24094  2543  2037 24153  2550  2088 24202  2557 27 24 24.5 10000.0    0.31     0.0 10000.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    0.65
```

I want to convert that entry to

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1936 24170  2536  1987 24094  2543  2037 24153  2550  2088 24202  2557 27 24 24.5 10000.0 10000.0 10000.0 10000.0 10000.0 10000.0 10000.0 10000.0
```

The important part is to keep the spacing and position of other columns intact.

---

Nearest thing I could do to accomplish my task is the following command.

```
gawk '{output=$0;for (i=0;i<8;i++){output=substr(output,0,97+8*i-1)"10000.0"substr(output, 97+8*(i+1)-1)}; print output}'
```

Comment: It would help if you could be specific, including an example input file along with expected output.

Comment: The example is somewhat helpful, but it's still unclear: Do you just want to replace the last 8 columns of numbers with `10000.0`?

Comment: Unlike shown in example above, I would like to substitute at giving fields (like $10, $13 etc). I shall take care that i don't make it insert anything which is bigger than the space available padded with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If the fields are fixed width, have you considered changing not by field number, but rather by column number?  You can do this in awk via substr(), or you could use cut.

e.g. assume the field you want is always in columns 56-60, you could do
  print substr($0,1,55) "text!" substr($0,61);

Comment: Since the field to substitute changes each time. I think i should make a look up table which stores the location in columns for each corresponding field and substitute there as you mentioned.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You aren't too specific about what you're doing, so I can't be specific here. That said:

What it sounds like you need to do is make your code modify `$0` directly rather than pick a field. `sub()` or `gsub()` may be useful to you, or you could "find" a field using `match()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added an example.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk, here's how to replace the 3rd field with the word "replacement":

```
$ cat file
field1      field2           field3    field4

$ gawk -v field=3 -v text="replacement" '{ print gensub("(^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){" field-1 "})[^[:space:]]+", "\\1" text, "") }' file
field1      field2           replacement    field4
```

In other awks you can do the same thing with sub()s or match()+substr()s.

To keep the field end position, assuming the replacement text is less than or equal to the length of the original plus it's preceding spaces:

```
$ cat file
field1      field2           field3    field4
  field1      field2           field3    field4

$ awk -v fieldNr=3 -v text="replacement" -f tst.awk file
field1      field2      replacement    field4
  field1      field2      replacement    field4

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    preFld="^([[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+){" fieldNr-1 "}"
}
{
    match($0,preFld)
    head = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)

    match($0,preFld "[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+")
    field = substr($0,RSTART+length(head),RLENGTH-length(head))

    printf("%s% *s%s\n", head, length(field), text, substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH))
}
```

For more info on the subject and different solutions, try the GNU gawk "patsplit()" function and/or FIELDWIDTHS variable.

Comment: Thankyou for the example. I wanted to keep the position of columns on right side of substitution also exactly as in input. I have added an example above in my question to make it clear.

Comment: You say you want to keep the spacing and positions but you can't have both unless the replacement fields are the same width as the originals. It looks like what you really want is to keep the positions, not the spacing which is completely different from your posted question.

Comment: I shall take care that i don't insert anything which is bigger than the space allowed for the field. By "preserving spacing", what i meant was the spacing of other columns which i am not changing. [This part of the problem is already solved by your suggestion to use substr()]